# MYSQL - How to correct SUBSELECT?

Tags: mysql, node-mysql

How to correct do an subselect Query in Node.js mysql?

*Example:*

```
TABLE1
|ID: (AI) |title: | content: | image_id |
|1        | some  | something|    1     |

TABLE 2
|ID: (AI) |title: | src:     |
|1        | any   | base64...|
```

Which result i want:

```
   select_result = [
     {
      title: some,
      content: something,
      image: {
             title: any,
             src: 'base64..'
             },
     }
    ]
```

What i tried:

```
SELECT title, content, (SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE id = image_id) as 'image' from TABLE1;
```

Error:

```
  code: 'ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS',
  errno: 1241,
  sqlMessage: 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)',
```

This subquery is working, but i need the other strucure:

```
SELECT title, content, (SELECT src FROM TABLE2 WHERE id = image_id) as 'image' from TABLE1;
```

Comment: Sub-queries used in the `SELECT` part of a query must return a single column, not multiple, as the error says.

Comment: Ho can i achieve to get this object?

Comment: A mysql result is always a flat array. If you want something multidimensional, I would suggest you do that in your application code.

Answer (score 1):

Sub-queries must return a single column, as you've discovered. If you want more columns, use a join not a sub-query.

```
SELECT t1.title, t1.content, t2.*
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.image_id;
```

Note: `LEFT JOIN` means the join is optional, i.e. it will still return items from table 1 even if there's no linked items in table 2. If the join is mandatory, use `JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN`.