# Fetch a column from one table, search the same column value in another table and finally fetch and display data from the third table

Tags: php, mysqli

Right, so I have a quite weird and complex question (you would've even noticed from the title of this question). I have two databases: **"admin"** and **"users"**. In the **"admin"** database I have a table called **"user_accounts"** where one of the column's name is **"course"**, this is what it looks like:

[image]

In the **"users"** database, I have 2 tables called **"booked courses"** and **"user_accounts"**, where the columns I need are **"email"**, **"user"** and **"course_name"**, this is what it looks like:

[image]

[image]

So, what I'm really trying to do is take the value of **"course"** column from the **"user_accounts"** table, check if it matches the records in the **"course_name"** column in the **"booked_courses"** table. If it does match ("business basics" in this case), then check what are the values of the **"user"** column in **"booked_courses"** table (copy both of the emails in this case) and then match those records with the **"email"** column in the **"user_accounts"** table (this time check it in the **"users"** database.

This is the code I have tried:

```
<?php

// Include the connection for the admin database

include_once 'handlers/db_conn_admin.php';

// Select and fetch the information from user_accounts table in the admin database

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE username = ?");
$sql->bind_param("s", $username);

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
$trainer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// Now include the connection for the users database

include_once 'handlers/db_conn_users.php';

// Select and fetch the information from booked_courses table in the users database where the course_name is whatever is the value of "course" column in user_accounts table in the admin database

$sql_booked_courses = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM booked_courses WHERE course_name=?");
$sql_booked_courses->bind_param("s", $course_name);

$course_name = $trainer['course'];

$sql_booked_courses->execute();
$result_booked_courses = $sql_booked_courses->get_result();
$email = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_booked_courses);

// Now select and fetch the information from user_accounts table in the users database where the email is whatever is the value of "user" column in booked_courses table in the users database

$sql_user_accounts = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE email=?");
$sql_user_accounts->bind_param("s", $user);

$user = $email['user'];

$sql_user_accounts->execute();
$result_user_accounts = $sql_user_accounts->get_result();

// And now for the end make the loop to display all the information about the users of the selected email addresses (in this case "email@example.com" and "email2@example.com")

while($user_info = $result_user_accounts->fetch_assoc()) {

?>

<h1><?php echo $user_info['email'] ?></h1>

<?php

}

?>
```

Right so, this actually does work, however at the end I'm only getting a single (oldest) result from the **"user_accounts"** table from the **"users"** database, when I need to get all the email addresses and display them on the HTML page. As i'm guessing since the "mysqli_fetch_assoc" function only gives you one value normally, I need to use the loop. The problem starts when I have 2 different email addresses with the same course column value. I'm not very sure how to make a loop into a loop or how to save the fetched results (in this case 2 email addresses) without a loop so that then I can display the info of the both rows, and I can't seem to find any solutions for this type of a situation.

I exactly know this probably sounds super confusing, complex and unnecessary, however I've built the whole system on these tables and this is the little feature I'm adding and I don't have much of a choice to combine tables or anything like that. Please someone help me out on this if you have any solutions, and let me know for any additional information you might need in the comments.

Comment: It is unfortunately a little hard to determine what the exact problem is, but you are using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` which will only ever return a single result. Would using `mysqli_fetch_all` which returns an array work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL - How to correct SUBSELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64260262/mysql-how-to-correct-subselect)

Comment: I’ll try in a sec and let you know, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisHaas Alright, I fixed it in a weird way but it works as intended now, I'll put up the script

Answer (score 1):

So what I actually did was I used while loop inside a while loop not to lose any of the fetched results from the database:

```
// EVERYTHING STAYS THE SAME ABOVE THIS CODE

$sql_booked_courses = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM booked_courses WHERE course_name=?");
$sql_booked_courses->bind_param("s", $course_name);

$course_name = $trainer['course'];

$sql_booked_courses->execute();
$result_booked_courses = $sql_booked_courses->get_result();

// I ADDED THIS CODE:

while($emails = $result_booked_courses->fetch_assoc()) {

$email = $emails['user'];

// Now select and fetch the information from user_accounts table in the users database where the email is whatever is the value of "user" column in booked_courses table in the users database

$sql_user_accounts = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE email=?");
$sql_user_accounts->bind_param("s", $user);

$user = $email['user'];

$sql_user_accounts->execute();
$result_user_accounts = $sql_user_accounts->get_result();

// And now for the end make the loop to display all the information about the users of the selected email addresses (in this case "email@example.com" and "email2@example.com")

while($user_info = $result_user_accounts->fetch_assoc()) {

?>

<h1><?php echo $user_info['email'] ?></h1>

<?php

} } // AND CLOSED THAT LOOP HERE (SO THERE IS A LOOP INSIDE A LOOP THAT WORKED

?>
```

I'm not sure how convenient that is but it works perfectly fine.